# ActiveAdmin saves has_and_belongs_to_many fields chosen but doesnt take effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have written the necessary code including the join table to create the many to many relationship between category and products and it works from testing in the rails console. When I chose more than one category field it saves them and stays there when I go back to edit it but when I view the product the default number is set.

I tried using

```
permit_params categories_ids: []
```

But it still wouldn't set the multiple chosen categories when I saved the product.

category.rb

```
has_ancestry
has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'ancestry'

has_and_belongs_to_many :products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true
```

product.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, allow_destroy: true
```

products.rb (ActiveAdmin)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
menu parent: "Shop"

scope :active, default: true
scope :disabled

filter :user
filter :categories
filter :personalisation
filter :name
filter :description
filter :out_of_stock
filter :price_cents
filter :weight

index do
    selectable_column
    column :name
    column :price
    column :description
    column :categories

    actions
end

form do |f|

  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :categories, as: :select, collection: Category.all, multiple: true   
  end
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `Activeadmin`, but this `categories_ids: []` should be `category_ids: []`

Comment: I had done this previously and still having the same problem